# How much disk space do I need for my Media Website?

Tags: html

I'm founding a new brand which is a News Media Site but I was wondering what is a good amount of disk space is good to dedicate to it. I was thinking of 2gb just to start off.

The website will just be filled with articles and the occasional video here and there.

Comment: Reddit is probably more appropriate for this kind of question.

Comment: Well if you put up a 2gb article then you only have room for that.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is a proper capacity planning exercise. You should figure out what is the average size of your news articles and videos. Then you need to ask yourself how much time do you want to have before you have to increase your storage space. From there you can figure out how much storage space you need to start.